# NavigationLink only works on long press SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationlink

For some reason it seems that my NavigationLink is only working on long press. Here's a snippet of the View:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: UserObservable
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List(user.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("\(user.displayName)'s items")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: AddItemViewButton().environmentObject(user),
                                    trailing: MainViewActionSheet().environmentObject(user))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The list is populated correctly but tapping on them does nothing. Pressing and holding and then releasing *does* open the correct destination.

Has anyone else seen anything like this? This is on Xcode 11.4.1 and iOS 13.4.1.

Comment: do you get the same behaviour if you put the  NavigationView before the VStack?

Comment: If I put the VStack inside the NavigationView or just remove the VStack wrapper altogether (I kinda forgot it was there) the bug remains. This same code worked for me on previous versions of Xcode too, which is strange.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Is behaviour the same if to comment `navigationBarItems`? If yes then it seems updated Xcode defect. I have not updated yet.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to all who helped, it turns out my issue was I had left an `onTapGesture` in my `SceneDelegate` that was supposed to close the keyboard when typing but instead kept my `NavigationLink`s from opening. Oops.

It looked a bit like this in case anyone runs into this issue too:

```swift
// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
        .environmentObject(user)
        .onTapGesture { window.endEditing(true) }) // <- Problem right there
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case also, my custom view had an onTapGesture. On removing the gesture, the issue got resolved.

```
  CarouselContentView(data: eachItem)
        .frame( height: 200, alignment: .center).onTapGesture {   
        } <== Removed it
```